# How does this regexp split on the first vowel?

Tags: ruby, regex

This code splits a word into two strings at the first vowel. Why?

```
word = "banana"
parts = word.split(/([aeiou].*)/)
```

Comment: Learn about regular expression. Any regex tutorial will teach you the use of `*`.

Comment: Check out http://rubular.com.  It's an online regular expression editor.  The reference guide explains that the asterisk means "zero or more of".

Comment: I think the question is actually about how the regexp interacts with Ruby's `split` method. This actually relies on a feature of Ruby I was not aware of until now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is the regular expression (or regex) that is being used between the two `/`'s

`[aeiou]` says to look for the first instance of one of those characters.

`.` matches any single character

`*` modifies the previous thing to mean match 0 or more of it

`(...)` means capture everything enclosed between the parentheses

Translated to english this regular expression might read something like "Given a string, find the first vowel that is followed by zero or more characters. Collect that vowel and its following characters and set them aside."

The slightly more confusing part is the regex's interaction with the `split` method. The value the regex returns is 'anana'. And we can see that  calling split with 'anana' doesn't have the same result:

`'banana'.split('anana') #=> ["b"]`

But when split is called with a regular expression that uses a capture group - or parentheses `(...)`, then anything in that capture group will also be returned in the result of the split. Which is why:

`'banana'.split /([aeiou].*)/ #=> ["b", "anana"]`

If you want to learn more about how regular expressions work (particularly in ruby), Rubular is a great resource to fiddle with - http://www.rubular.com/r/XEUgPhOdlH

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER FOR OLD TITLE**

It's not really a Ruby's syntax, it's a standard [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)'s syntax that also implemented by Ruby.

- `*` means zero or more of previous item
- `.` means any character
- `[aeiou]` means any character inside the brace
- `()` means capture it

So that regex means: capture anything that starts with `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`.

the `word.split(/([aeiou].*)/)` means, split the `word` variable based on anything that starts with letter `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`.

See here fore [more](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) information.

**ANSWER FOR NEW TITLE**

Why does it split on the first vowel? It's not really like that.. What it does is, split by anything that start with vowels and capture it (the string that starts with vowels) also, see more example here:

```
word = 'banana'
word.split /[aeiou]/ # split by vowels
#=> ["b", "n", "n"] 
word.split /([aeiou])/  # split by vowels and capture the vowels
#=> ["b", "a", "n", "a", "n", "a"]
word.split /[aeiou].*/ # split by anything that start with vowels
#=> ["b"]
word.split /([aeiou].*)/ # split by anything that start with vowels and capture the thing that start with vowels also
#=> ["b", "anana"]
```

**ANSWER FOR OLD TITLE**

If the `*` symbol not inside the regular expression `//` (Ruby's syntax), there are some possibilities:

- multiplication `2 * 3 == 6`, `'na' * 3 == 'nanana' # batman!`
- splat operation `[*(1..4)] == [1,2,3,4]`, see more info [here](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)

Comment: This explains what the regexp matches, but it does not explain at all why it results in the string split on the first vowel. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bit tricky. This regexp

```
/[aeiou].*/
```

matches the string from the first vowel to the end of the string i.e. "anana". But if you were to split on that, you would only get the first letter since `split` doesn't include the splitting pattern:

```
"banana".split /[aeiou].*/
# ["b"]
```

But according to the [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) docs, if the splitting pattern is a regexp with a capture group, the capture groups are included in the result as well. Since the whole pattern is wrapped in a capture group, the result is that the string splits before the first vowel.

For example, if you change the regexp to have two capture groups, it splits further:

```
"banana".split /([aeiou])(.*)/
# ["b", "a", "nana"]
```